# How to share the same object between two processes?

Tags: java, jvm, share

I am providing a service for instant messaging among users. In this program, there are mainly two Class, one for notification, the other as a switchboard, just like the MSN. Now I have to share a Map object between these two Class(independent processes), and this Map will be traversed frequently.
How can I share this Map object in a efficiently way?

### EDIT ##

I think storing the object into HD and then reading it from HD would not be efficiently, considering that I have to traverse it frequently.
Can I use a way like Memory Map in C? How?

Comment: Posting a code sample may increase your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Pass a reference to the map to both constructors when you create the instances.

Comment: @eebbesen I just want to use the same Map object between two Class.

Comment: Singleton Wrapper Object of Map and implement of Serializable ?

Comment: @VanVu singleton is the worst option for this case.

Comment: @PeterLawrey It's two independent processes, how can I implement that?

Comment: You cannot share a Map between processes. I would put them in the same JVM if they must be shared.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : then how about using serialize ... store Map to HD/Ram and de-serialize with the read process ??? http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/serialization/

Comment: @VanVu the classes are in different processes (not sure if different threads or different JVMs). The best solution would be load the `Map` once and pass its reference in the constructor of the classes that need this `Map`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It sounds work in different threads, but how if in different JVMs?

Comment: If in different JVMs, then have a source to load the data into your `Map` (probably a properties file), then use a class to load the `Map` with the values from your source and pack it in a jar (and also the properties file). On each application, use this jar and load the contents of the `Map` based on the same source. If the source can change from one of these applications, it would be better using a database instead of a properties file.

Comment: I cringe to suggest it, but if the object is in different JVM's/processes, why not serialize the object and pass it to and fro using UDP/TCP as necessary, or just pass the updates?

Answer (score 0):

Try using MemoryMappedByteBuffer from Java NIO